# Swift 3 ObjectMapper - casting URLSession result to Map object fails

Tags: ios, json, swift3, objectmapper

How am I supposed to fetch JSON object using URLSession so I will be able to cast it to Map object from ObjectMapper? This is my code for fetching data from API server:

```
func makeGetRequest(completionHandler: @escaping ((AnyObject?) -> Void)) {
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    guard let requestUrl = URL(string:buildUrl()) else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url:requestUrl)

    //HEADERS
    request.addValue("multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");

    let token = CredentialsManager.sharedInstance().token;
    if (!(token?.isEmpty)!) {
        request.addValue(token!, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Auth-Token");
    };

    let task : URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        do {
            let resultJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            completionHandler(resultJSON as AnyObject?)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // Handle error
        }
    });

    task.resume()
}
```

This is function where I call for the data to be fetched:

```
public func getUser() {
    makeGetRequest() { (result) -> Void in
        let resultModel = UserModel(map: result as! Map)
        self.resultDelegate.onUserRequestSuccess(model: resultModel!)
    }
}
```

And here is my UserModel implementing mappable protocol:

```
class UserModel : Mappable {

var id: Int?
var username: String?

required init?(map: Map) {

}

// Mappable
func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
    username <- map["username"]
}
```

}

And while calling

`UserModel(map: result as! Map)`

I get the error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' to 'NSArray'

Answer (score 0):

> Get response in using JSONSerialization below is code for ObjectMapper:

```
 let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": authBearer]

 Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: headers).responseJSON { response  in
            print(response.result.value ?? "")
            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: [])
            let report = Mapper<Department>().map(JSON: json as! [String : Any])
            print(report?.department[0].employee[0].first_name ?? "")
 }

class Department: Mappable {
    var department = [Directory]()

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
    department <- map["department"]
    }

}

class Directory:Mappable {
    var id = 0
    var name = ""
    var employee = [Employee]()
    var genre = ""

    //Impl. of Mappable protocol
    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id    <- map["id"]
        name <- map["name"]
        employee <- map["employee"]
        genre <- map["genre"]
    }
}

class Employee: Mappable {
    var address = ""
    var dob = ""
    var email = ""
    var first_name = ""
    var last_name = ""
    var phone_number = ""

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        address <- map["address"]
        dob <- map["dob"]
        email <- map["email"]
        first_name <- map["first_name"]
        last_name <- map["last_name"]
        phone_number <- map["phone_number"]

    }
}
```